# POST request returns an HTML response instead of a JSON response (C#)

Tags: c#

Unfortunately, I am having the following problem.

I am making a `POST` request to an API via C# and the `HttpClient`, but the API returns an HTML page. However, I am expecting a JSON response, which I am also getting via Postman.

This is my code:

```
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.UseCookies = false;
    handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

    using var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, ApiRequestUris.StoreDocumentUri);
    
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var departments = GetDepartments(documentModel, builder);
    var categories = GetCategories(documentModel, builder);
    var status = GetStatus(documentModel, builder);

    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Jobrouter-Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
    
    var content = await BuildMultipartFormDataContentAsync(documentModel, categories, departments, status, cancellationToken);
    
    request.Content = content;

    var responseContent = await client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    var response = await responseContent.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
    responseContent.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

HTML response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
</body></html>
```

Postman response:

```
{
    "archivedocumentrevisions": [
        {
            "revisionId": "602"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "locations": [
            "/api/rest/v2/application/jobarchive/archives/CEE96938-7F53-4E79-8331-029FA1E7FBC8/documents/602/file",
            "/api/rest/v2/application/jobarchive/archives/CEE96938-7F53-4E79-8331-029FA1E7FBC8/documents/602/files",
            "/api/rest/v2/application/jobarchive/archives/CEE96938-7F53-4E79-8331-029FA1E7FBC8/documents/602/clippedfiles"
        ]
    }
}
```

And yes, obviously I am not authorised. But I don't understand why, because the access token is the same as the one Postman uses. The body and header are also identical.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that API might be expecting a request in specific format or encoding

Comment: The API might require a User-Agent header, which HttpClient doesn't send by itself.

Comment: 403 means you're trying to access something that you should not access and it is rejected by the server itself. a file, a directory, etc... This situation usually happens when url is not correct or the target server is not up or expecting requests like you have sent.